# Proof help: RSA Encryption

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am trying to fill in the middle of this proof:

$$ \begin{align}
 m_1 ^e \mod N \cdot \left( m_2 ^e \mod N\right)^{-1}\mod N & = \\
& \quad \vdots \\
& = \left( \frac {m_1}{m_2}\right)^e\mod N
\end{align}$$

where:

- $e$ is a random number such that $\gcd \left( \varphi(N),e \right)=1$
- $N=pq$ for $p,q$ prime
- $m_1$ and $m_2$ can be any integer such that $m_1=k\cdot m_2$ for
  $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Simply put, I am trying to prove RSA Encryption is a partially homomorphic encryption system for division.

I have the proof for multiplication, but I'm struggling to modify it to account for the inverses. Any help is much appreciated!

---

*Edit: This is my current attempt at a proof*

The following is RSA encryption and decryption of messages $m_1$ and $m_2$:

$$
\begin{align}
c_1 = m_1^e \mod N & \Longleftrightarrow m_1 = c_1^d \mod N\\
c_2 = m_2^e \mod N & \Longleftrightarrow m_2 = c_2^d \mod N
\end{align}
$$

For multiplication, I have the following proof:

$$\begin{align*}
m & =\left(c_{1}c_{2}\right)^{d}\mod N\\
 & =\left(c_{1}c_{2}\mod N\right)^{d}\mod N\\
 & =\left(\left(c_{1}\mod N\times c_{2}\mod N\right)\mod N\right)^{d}\mod N\\
 & =\left(c_{1}\mod N\times c_{2}\mod N\right)^{d}\mod N\\
 & =\left(\left(c_{1}\mod N\right)^{d}\times\left(c_{2}\mod N\right)^{d}\right)\mod N\\
 & =\left(\left(c_{1}^{d}\mod N\right)\times\left(c_{2}^{d}\mod N\right)\right)\mod N\\
 & =\left(m_{1}m_{2}\right)\mod N\\
 & =m_{1}m_{2}
\end{align*}$$

For division I have the following attempt:

$$\begin{align*}
m & = \left(c_{1}\cdot c_{2}^{-1}\mod N\right)^{d}\\
 & =\left(\left(c_{1}\mod N\times c_{2}^{-1}\mod N\right)\mod N\right)^{d}\\
 & =\left(c_{1}\mod N\times c_{2}^{-1}\mod N\right)^{d}\\
 & =\left(c_{1}\mod N\right)^{d}\times\left(c_{2}^{-1}\mod N\right)^{d}\\
 & =\left(c_{1}^{d}\mod N\right)\times\left(c_{2}^{-1}\mod N\right)^{d}\\
 & =m_{1}\times\left(c_{2}^{-1}\mod N\right)^{d}\\
 & =m_{1}\times\left(c_{2}^{d}\mod N\right)^{-1}\tag{this step looks dodgy}\\
 & =m_{1}\times m_{2}^{-1}\\
 & =\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: doesn't the multiplication property imply it for division? You're proved already encryption is a homomorphism.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That's the bit I'm having problems with - seeing why exactly the multiplication property implies it for division.

Comment: @lioness99a: Because division is, in fact, multiplication?

Comment: Have edited above - the multiplicative inverses are causing me the issues, it's not actually division, it's multiplcation by an inverse...